# Getting "java.lang.AssertionError" while running scripts using Cucumebr TestNG Framework. It appears intermittently with different cases

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, assertion, test-suite

I have been running Cucumber TestNG framework. Whenever i execute suite on remote machine (on one of the AWS instance), some times suite runs perfectly fine without any issues.
But most of the times 2-3 test cases fails and gets the below error.
It doesn't fail because of any element identification. It's really hard to find out the exact cause. Its very intermittent.
Has anyone faced this issue?
Your help much appreciated!

Framework: Cucumber TestNG
Java version: 8
Cucumber Version:

```
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
<version>7.3.4</version>
            
Cucumber-TestNG version:
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
<version>7.3.4</version>
`
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>4.9.0</version>
```

Actual Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.replaceInParent(LinkedTreeMap.java:318)
`   at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.removeInternal(LinkedTreeMap.java:291)
    at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.removeInternalByKey(LinkedTreeMap.java:302)
    at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.remove(LinkedTreeMap.java:134)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.GherkinDialect.<init>(GherkinDialect.java:25)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.GherkinDialectManager.setLanguage(GherkinDialectManager.java:76)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.setGherkinDialect(ExtentReports.java:446)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.createFeature(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:314)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.handleStartOfFeature(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:307)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.handleTestCaseStarted(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:161)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.access$100(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:63)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$3.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:107)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$3.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:104)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SynchronizedEventBus.send(SynchronizedEventBus.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$LocalEventBus.send(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:62)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.emitTestCaseStarted(TestCase.java:206)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:72)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
... Removed 9 stack frames
```

I have tried locally and those works fine. But fails on remote machine.

Comment: Without knowing more about your tests and the system under test it going to be hard for us to help you find the root cause of your flaky tests. Common causes can include: timeouts, asynch, race conditions, data being manipulated by other tests, not being in control of tests' preconditions (data/state), environment issues, etc. I would start by check which scenarios are flaky and what (if anything) they have in common that might be the underlying cause of their flakiness.